# How do I make a UICollectionView transparent?

Tags: swift, collectionview

I have tried virtually (literally?) everything to make a horizontal collection view transparent which is overlaid on a map view.

This is my collection view:

```
fileprivate let restaurantCollection : UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        let restaurant = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        restaurant.decelerationRate = .fast
        restaurant.backgroundView = nil
        restaurant.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        restaurant.backgroundColor = .clear
        restaurant.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        restaurant.register(MapCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        return restaurant
    }()
```

As you can see it has a clear background, clear layer and the background view is nil.

And the cell is transparent as well:

```
func setupView() {
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.withAlphaComponent(0)

    contentView.addSubview(cellBackground)
    cellBackground.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cellBackground.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    cellBackground.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    cellBackground.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    cellBackground.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

I also added a view to the cell "backgroundView" that's pinned with constant 0 to all sides. And this too is clear.

```
lazy var cellBackground : UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: self.frame.width, height: 220))
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    return view
}()
```

And after all that effort, the collection view still has a white background
[image]

View hierarchy: Here is the view that is still white

[image]
[image]

Comment: any view behind the image other than the contentView

Comment: Make sure to set your view isOpaque property to false

Comment: have you checked it in https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html

Comment: Examine the View Hierarchy to see whose views white color it is ....

Comment: I checked the view heirarchy and it's the UICollectionView that's the problem. However, I have already set that isOpaque = false

Comment: @jawadAli I added the screenshots above. Thanks.

Comment: remove this line `restaurant.backgroundView = nil`

Comment: if it did not resolve use this line instead `restaurant.backgroundView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.zero)`

Comment: I tried the above. Also tried restaurant.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.1) and I still get a solid white background for the collection view!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213639/discussion-between-jawadali-and-bvb09).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are setting `backgroundColor` to clear

```
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.collectionView.backgroundView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Modern List Layout CollectionViews:

```
UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration.backgroundColor = .clear
UICollectionViewListCell.backgroundConfiguration = .clear()
```